# Cant Get HashMap value from key in the HashMap

Tags: kotlin, hashmap

I'm trying to get the value of a specific Key.

I have a `Hasmap<Account, someValue>`. I have a unique key to identify each account, by id.
Account is a data class I defined.

```
data class Account (var name : String, val OwnerEmail : String, val sharedUsersEmailList : HashMap <String,Boolean>, val ExpenseKeyList : HashMap <String,Boolean>){
    constructor(): this("" , "", hashMapOf(),hashMapOf())
```

`m_accountseExpense` - this is the hashmap.

I use the next code to get the Account from the HashMap:

```
private fun GetAccountFromList(accountId : String): Account? {
    val accountList = m_accountseExpense.keys
    accountList.forEach{
        if (it.GetAccountId() == accountId){
            Log.w("hashcode", it.hashCode().toString())
            return it
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

This function returns the Account from the HashMap.

After I got the Account from the function, I try to get the value, but I get `null`.

I even try to run this code to validate it:

```
val accountToShow = GetAccountFromList(m_accountToShowKey)
// in here I'm getting the Account from the hashmap
Log.w("hashcode", accountToShow.hashCode().toString())
val temp = m_accountseExpense.containsKey(accountToShow)
Log.w("hashcode", temp.toString())
```

after I get the Account I check if it is in the Hashmap, and I get false.
although, I get the account, and all the values are the same, and
The hashCode is the same, and I can't get the value of this Account.
when I try to get the value of m_accountseExpense[accountToShow] i get null.
Any suggestion?
Thank you very much

edit :

```
fun GetAccountId() : String{
    return this.name+ "_" + CreateUserId(this.OwnerEmail)
}

fun CreateUserId(email: String) : String
{
    val firstDotIndex = email.indexOf(".")
    return email.substring(0,firstDotIndex)
}
```

Comment: What does `Account.GetAccountId()` look like?

Comment: I update the code, the GetAccountId is just a string

Comment: Are you sure `m_accountseExpense` map is not modified in another thread?

Will it work with `m_accountseExpense.entries.find { (key, value) -> key.GetAccountId() == accountId }?.value` ?

Comment: I didn't think to use lambda, thank you @МихаилНафталь, but i still would like to understand what went wrong.
 im almost sure a thread didnt change it, I look at all the value, and all the hascode are the same in all of them.
I do use this logic in a callback and im doing in on MutableLiveData, but i don't think other thread change the values.